# Error while attaching mdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

While attaching a mdf file in sql server i got `unable to open the physical file name.mdf` error. how to resolve this error?

Comment: Is the file accessible, not read only, not open in any other process? Checked Network Permissions etc. ?

Comment: Voting for migration to Serverfault since administrating a database server is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am referring below URL forum thread in which the topic "Unable to open physical file - Operating system error 5: 5(error not found) Microsoft SQL Server: Error 5120" discussed..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9e563890-e35f-4524-82b9-3cca08fec5ed

I hope in this various solutions have and trying to solve by using anyone of them.